# Aggregate result of table valued UDF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a table valued UDF (it returns a number of rows). How can I aggregate the table valued results in a SQL query?

I'd like to do something like

```
select GetMyTableValuedResults(MyColumn1)
from MyTable
```

But this TSQL doesn't compile...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT res.*
FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetMyTableValuedResults(MyColumn1) res
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. I get just the total number of rows in MyTable, not the rows in MyTable x table valued UDF result rows. Any idea why?

Comment: Specifically, I only get the first result from my table valued function